# I want to select a table from a database and show in a drop down list

Tags: php, html, mysql

I wanted to select a table from a specific database and then the list of tables will appear in an option tag under select tag.

Thanks a lot.

Current Code:

```
<?php

include 'database/connectdatabase.php';

if(isset($_POST['select_db']))
{
    $select_db = $_POST['select_db'];
    $selectdb_query = 'SHOW TABLES FROM $select_db';
    $query_select = mysql_query($selectdb_query,$connectDatabase);  

if(!$query_select)
{
    echo 'NO table selected!';
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="selecttable.php" autocomplete="off">
  <select name="select_db">
    <option  selected="selected">Select Database</option>
    <option>section_masterfile</option>
  </select>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="#" autocomplete="off">
  <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query_select)) {
    $num_row = mysql_num_rows($row);?>
    <select name="select_table">
        <option  selected="selected">Select Table</option>
            <?php for($i=0;$i>=$num_row;i++){?>
                <option><?php echo $row[0];?></option>
            <?php}?>
    </select>
  <?php}?>
</form>
```

Comment: Errors if any? Checking for them? Plus, you should space these out a bit `<?php}?>` - `<?php } ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're already fetching rows yet you haven't even submitted the form yet.

I suggest restructure you logic this way:

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$tables = array();
if(isset($_POST['select_db'])) { // if its submitted
    $select_db = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['select_db']); // escape the string
    $query = $con->query("SHOW TABLES FROM $select_db");
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tables[] = $row['Tables_in_' . $select_db]; // use associative instead
    }
}


?>

<form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <select name="select_db" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option disabled selected>Select Database</option>
        <option>test</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    <select name="select_table">
        <?php foreach($tables as $table): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $table; ?>"><?php echo $table; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Sidenote: If you have turned on the error reporting, this should have given some red light to what you are doing wrong. Kindly turn it on.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: +1 the best answer for this. Most up-to-date as well.

Comment: @Darren yep seems logical to write an answer with the newer api since its a short code anyways

Comment: @Ghost Thanks you save half of my life (GAYISH MODE.)

Comment: Hi @Ghost maybe you can help me with this problem also :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/26272517/4078247

Comment: hello @Jeff check out the first answer on that question, i think that would also be my answer

Comment: @Ghost For the life of me, I couldn't get this to work lol - I'm always getting `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in...` maybe it's because I'm having trouble following the way the script works. It's probably just me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if im going to diagnose on my side, i'd say the query has the problem, you sure you got those db_name correct? try to hardcode it to check `select tables from information_schema` or something like that

Comment: @Ghost I think the issue may lie in `$row['Tables_in_' . $select_db];` - it's the `Tables_in_` that I'm not quite sure about. This I presume `<option>test</option>` - `test` being the database or table?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes its the db name, the result set column will yield `Tables_in_(DB_NAME)` thats why i concatenated the db name on that associative array index

Comment: @Ghost Ok thanks Ghost. I'm not going to have us spend too much time on this. It's really not important. I like to mess around with given code sometimes just to test its functionality. +1 though. I'll fool around with this once I get some time. Got some work that just came in now, so I'll be busy for a few hours. Take it easy, ciao.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thats quite odd, actually i've tested it on my env before posting, sure man no prob

Comment: @Fred-ii- lol i wasn't thinking that way. yeah me too new projects coming up so can't so im just picking my spots on answering on a good day. anyway. im off to lahlah land.. cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="select_table">
  <option  selected="selected">Select Table</option>
  <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query_select)) { ?>
      <option value = "<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<form method="POST" action="#" autocomplete="off">

    <select name="select_table">
        <option  selected="selected">Select Table</option>
            <?php 
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query_select)) 
                {
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row[0];?>"><?php echo $row[0];?></option>
            <?php 
                } 
            ?>
    </select>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
 <form method="POST" action="#" autocomplete="off">

    <select name="select_table">
        <option  selected="selected">Select Table</option>
    <?php 
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query_select)) {
    ?>

        <option><?php echo $row[0];?></option>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </select>
</form>
```