# Select all data from a table and insert it to another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, insert

I wanted to select all the data from one of my table and insert it to another table. I have this code but it wasn't working..This is what the phpMyadmin says "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0010 seconds.)"

**Here is my code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['select_table']))
{
    $select_table = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['select_table']);
    $query_select = "INSERT INTO pdf_table
                    SELECT * FROM $select_table";
    $select_query = mysql_query($query_select,$connectDatabase);
}
```

Comment: Did you checked you have data in the table from which you are selecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure that both the tables have equal number of columns.
It is a good practice to use following way for inserting records with select query :-

```
INSERT INTO pdf_table (column_1, column_2) SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM $select_table
```

Answer (score 2):

your sql query is like

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column_name(s)) SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are using  `INSERT INTO pdf_table SELECT * FROM $select_table` will give you only single row inserted from 1st table to another table.

As per your requirement you want all the records from 1st table should get insert in your **pdf_table**
So i will like to suggest try the following approach
May be this is what you looking for

```
if(isset($_POST['select_table']))
{
    $select_table = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['select_table']);

    $select_query = mysql_query( "select * from $select_table ",$connectDatabase);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_query))
    {
         mysql_query( "insert into pdf_table values($row['column1'],$row['column2'],...,$row['columns']) ",$connectDatabase);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
if(isset($_POST['select_table']))
{
    $select_table = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['select_table']);
    $query_select = " Create Table pdf_table ( SELECT * FROM $select_table); ";
    $select_query = mysql_query($query_select,$connectDatabase);
}
```

but, this query will create new table "pdf_table".